# sbcl on SUSE 10 x86-64 error: floating point exception

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I download the http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sbcl/sbcl-1.0.51-x86-64-linux-binary.tar.bz2 and install in  SUSE 10 x86-64. But when run sbcl it error say: floating point exception

and http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sbcl/sbcl-1.0.51-x86-linux-binary.tar.bz2 is the same error.

should I compile sbcl from source?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the error, but compiling SBCL only takes ~30 minutes or so, so I'd definitely try that out.

Comment: very thanks.then I will try to compile it.

Comment: In order to make sure it isn't something in your configuration, you should try `sbcl --no-sysinit --no-userinit` to start SBCL without loading any external code.

Comment: Isn't your processor very old?